# Install Windows after Ubuntu ? + Grub doesn't appear

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, bios

I recently tried to install a dual-boot Windows 7/Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer. But I didn't notice that my installation of Windows wasn't compatible with dual-boot installation (because I installed in BIOS mode rather than U-EFI mode). So obviously I can't access to Windows since.
So, if I understand correctly, I have to reinstall Windows, right ?
I wonder, since I didn't lost any of my data from Windows,do I just have to erase the system partition of my old Windows, and then follow this tutorial : https://www.techsolveprac.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual/ (which seems OK to me)?
Or is more complicated than that ? Is there any other options (maybe better) than this ?

Another problem is that Grub doesn't appear when my computer is booting (but I still get the screen of the BIOS of my motherboard). Is it related to my previous installation of Windows on BIOS mode ? 
I already check for re-installation of Grub with forum advises but it didn't work (I don't remember what I did to be honest sorry :/).

Since I tried not to make this post too long, there are some parts unclear, so feel free to ask anything that might be useful to help you understand (specs on my motherboard for example), and thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Windows 7 is not supported anymore from microsoft, no security updates.  You should try to install Win 10.  Having an Ubuntu live USB handy for after Win install is useful to re install grub.

Comment: Hi @crip659, I have a Ubuntu live-key with me ! For the windows part I was sure that I had to pass to W10. But apart form that, is my method OK ?

Comment: Both OSs should be booted the same way, legacy(bios) or UEFI.  Win 10 does have some legal ways to install for free(google), saves time installing 7 then 10.  Install of Windows sometimes over writes grub, so it might need to be re installed, less so with UEFI.  A Win 7 license might be enough, Microsoft call can help.